# Python updating a sql DB

Tags: python, sql

Have a program that recieves a list of player names and results. Then trys to add them to a SQL DB. If the player name is already on the list I want it to update there Score by adding there current score to the stored one. I'm trying to do this by using the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement but I'm unsure how to tell it to use the value. Here is my code.

```
from mysql.connector.cursor import MySQLCursorPrepared
print(playerNames ,playerScore )
try:
    #MariaDB Connection
    con = mysql.connector.connect(port=5004,user='root',password='password',host='localhost',database='scoreboard')
    records_to_insert = [ (playerNames[0],playerScore[0]) ,
                        (playerNames[1],playerScore[1]),
                        (playerNames[2],playerScore[2]) ,
                        (playerNames[3],playerScore[3]) 
                        ]
    sql_insert_query = " INSERT INTO results (Player, Score) VALUES (%s,%s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Score = VALUES(Score) + %s; "
    myCursor = con.cursor()
    myCursor.executemany(sql_insert_query, records_to_insert)

    con.commit()
```

I know the issue is with using "= VALUES(Score) + %s" but I'm not sure of how else to tell it what value I want to use there. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use this expression:

```
INSERT INTO results (Player, Score)
    VALUES (%s, %s)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Score = VALUES(Score) + Score;
```

Notes:

- This assumes that you have a unique index on `Player` (or better yet, it is the primary key).
- You should learn to use SQL parameters for passing in values, rather than string substitution.
- You might want to declare `Score` to be `NOT NULL` to ensure that it always has reasonable values.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Player is a primary key and Score is set to be Not Null.

Answer (score -1):

```
 sql_insert_query = " INSERT INTO results (Player, Score) VALUES {0},{1}) ON DUPLICATE 
 KEY UPDATE Score = VALUES(Score) + {1}; ".format(playerNames[0],playerScore[1])
```